# How did Bourne shell solve missing teletype keys problem?

Tags: history, bourne-shell

I've learned recently from [DigitalRoss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7828178/3701431) that certain teletypes such as ASR-33 lacked certain keys; for instance `|`. For that purpose in C there exist trigraph operators that can be substituted for `|` and some others.

Now, this begs the question what was done in Bourne shell back in the day to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of ^ as a shell metacharacter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104318/use-of-as-a-shell-metacharacter)

Comment: Trigraphs in C were not introduced because of the Teletype Model 33, they came much later. The reason for trigraphs were the ISO-646 character set, which allowed certain characters like `{|}` to be replaced by national characters like `äöå`.

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not answer the question of how one entered these characters (more than just `|`) when that sort of teletype was a Unix terminal.  Unfortunately this question is written as if the shell were all that one interacted with on a terminal.